# Webservice+consumer c# error Server was unable to process request. ---> The connection is already open

Tags: c#, web-services

i have a webservice and a comsumer, the webservice has its methode where it returns data from a mysql database.
in the comsumer i called

```
WebService.Service1 Service = new WebService.Service1();
```

in the beginning (not within a methode)
when the consumer starts asking for data it will be 20 requests within 10 minutes first 15-18 requests worked perfectly but the last few times it returns the error

> Server was unable to process request. ---> The connection is already
>   open.

I hope i provided enough information like this, i rather not post the code.

This is the methode of the webservice:

```
        public string GetAnswer(string Question, string Option1, string Option2, string Option3, string Option4)
    {
        string connstring = "Server=Server;Port=3306;Database=DB;UID=User;password=pw;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
        MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();

        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `tbl` where `Question` = '" + Question + "' LIMIT 1";
        conn.Open();

        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            string TheAnswer = "";
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string question = reader["Question"].ToString();
                string answer = reader["Answer"].ToString();
                if (Option1.Equals(answer))
                    TheAnswer = Option1;
                if (Option2.Equals(answer))
                    TheAnswer = Option2;
                if (Option3.Equals(answer))
                    TheAnswer = Option3;
                if (Option4.Equals(answer))
                    TheAnswer = Option4;
            }
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
            return TheAnswer;
        }
        else
        {
            MySqlCommand command2 = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "Insert Into `new` (`Question`, `Answer1`,`Answer2`,`Answer3`,`Answer4`) VALUES ('" + Question + "','" + Option1 + "','" + Option2 + "','" + Option3 + "', '" + Option4.Replace("~", " ") + "')";
            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
            return "Error: Question is unknown, saving the question to get it answered.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: web service code has a possible connection layer problem.. you should provide informaton about your connection management.

Comment: Where do you get the exception? Is it when the client calls the web service, or is it an error within the server that is passed on to the client? If it is the latter, it can be related to how you handle the mysql db connections.

Comment: @AndersAbel i get the exception when calling a methode on the client, it is asfar i know not related to how i do the mysql connection as i close and dispose these

Comment: Session issue ? Maybe your user session is going to be close due to timeout.

Comment: @hkutluay how can i show the connection management (not that experienced with webservices)

Comment: @ykatchou wouldn't the exception be "Session Timeout" then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `conn.open()` in your else statement, and the connection was already opened before that.  You should probably consider using the `using` statement:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring))
{
  using (MySqlCommand command2 = conn.CreateCommand())
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are completely right i see it now, this is stupid of me!
thanks for noticing it!